# How to correctly pop a modeless dialog from console using MFC

Tags: mfc, console, dialog, modeless

I need to create a console application that has a **main()** function and pop a **modeless dialog**, so the console can still work in parallel to the modeless dialog (do other work, like communicating with the modeless dialog).

Whatever i tried, i could only pop a **modal** dialog. (where the console is in hold till the modal dialog close itself).

When switching to **modeless** dialog using Create() and ShowWindow() the dialog is displayed without its controls and it **freeze / block** (you can see the hourglass cursor).

1) I tried to pop the modeless dialog from the main() function:

```
void main()
{
    AfxWinInit(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), SW_SHOW);

    TestGUI * gui;
    gui = new TestGUI();
    gui->Create(TestGUI::IDD);
    gui->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    // just to see if the modeless dialog responses
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

2) I tried to pop the modeless dialog from the InitInstance() of a CWinApp derived class:

```
extern int AFXAPI AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                             HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                             LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        gui = new TestGUI();
        gui->Create(TestGUI::IDD);
        gui->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

        return TRUE;
    }

private:
    TestGUI * gui;
};

MyApp my_app;

void main()
{
    AfxWinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), SW_SHOW);

    // just to see if the modeless dialog responses
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

In all cases the modeless dialog freeze.

I believe this is a one line solution.
Please help.

TNX,
Vertilka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code snippet solves the problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestGUI.h"

DWORD WINAPI ModelessThreadFunc(LPVOID)
{
  TestGUI gui;
  gui.Create(TestGUI::IDD);
  gui.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

  HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"CloseModelessDialog");

  MSG msg;
  while(WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    while(::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
      ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
      ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }

  // event cleanup
  CloseHandle(hEvent);

  return 0;
}

void main()
{
  // initialize MFC
  AfxWinInit(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLine(), SW_SHOW);

  // create thread for the modeless dialog
  CreateThread(NULL, 0, ModelessThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);

  // wait for the modeless dialog to close itself
  HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"CloseModelessDialog");
  while(WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    // do other job
  }

  // event cleanup
  CloseHandle(hEvent);
}
```

Also look at the following link: [microsoft newsgroups](https://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vc.mfc&tid=66957915-3dfb-4317-8c27-df7fe87fe5d1&cat=en_US_f0847235-3112-4b9a-8717-b82f7898eeea&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1)